# Writing NDB Property Subclass

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I am writing ImgProperty in which I would like to give a user a way to define default height and width, like this:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  img = ImgProperty(height=32, width=32)
```

and then:

```
m = MyModel(img='https://example.com/my-photo')
```

the image then will be saved to the db resized to given height, width values.
The ImgProperty itself subclasses BlobProperty. Can I add those two attribute to Property._attributes and thus make it work? Or better not to mess with it? The other way I see to do it, is to create an intermediate model with fields height and width and add `__init__` method to ImgProperty.
Something like this:

```
class ImgModel(ndb.Model):
  height = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  width = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class ImgProperty(ndb.BlobProperty):
  def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super(ImgProperty, self).__init__(ImgModel, **kwds)
```

I'm not sure if this way will allow definition like `img = ImgProperty(height=32, width=32)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer your question about the constructor signature.  You should be able to do it as follows:

```
class ImgProperty(ndb.BlobProperty):
  def __init__(self, height=32, width=32, **kwds):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    super(ImgProperty, self).__init__(**kwds)
```

For the rest I suppose you are following the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop

I can't really help you with the resizing (use the image api); however I wonder if you aren't better off making the resize call by hand before you store the data into the property value, just to avoid unnecessary extra resize calls to the image api; the automatic property transforms are very powerful but may occasionally make redundant calls.

Good luck!

Comment: This is the way i did it in the end, much simpler than the first 2 ways i thought about (got confused by the docs). I do the resizing in _to_base_type() using image api and return the product to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also save the get_serving_url including the size. In this way you make use of the Google High Performance Image serving API, where Google serves the Image.

From the doc: This URL format allows dynamic resizing and cropping, so you don't need to store different image sizes on the server. Images are served with low latency from a highly optimized, cookieless infrastructure.

Here is an example: https://lh6.ggpht.com/lOghqU2JrYk8M-Aoio8WjMM6mstgZcTP0VzJk79HteVLhnwZy0kqbgVGQZYP8YsoqVNzsu0EBysX16qMJe7H2BsOAr4j=s70

For more information see this blog post: http://googleappengine.blogspot.nl/2010/08/multi-tenancy-support-high-performance_17.html

Comment: From what i understand get_serving_url retrieves the images after they were saved to datastore. It is another approach to what i was asking, to save the height and width and resize when serving it.

Comment: The images are saved in the blobstore. Your key is the blobkey. With this blobkey you can get a get_serving_url. When you save this get_serving_url link in the datastore you can include the size. Look at my example '..s70' means size=70. Serving these images this way have a lot of advantages. Clear?
By the way. You only need one size, because the apspect ratio will be maintained. See the docs.